# Let $p\gt 3$ be a prime number and: $\sum_{j=1}^{p-1}\frac{(-1)^{j}}{j} \binom{p-1}{j} =\frac{a}{b}\Rightarrow p^2\mid a$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, alternative-proof

I want to prove the following statement:

> Let $p\gt 3$ be a prime number and let:
>   $$\sum_{j=1}^{p-1}\frac{(-1)^{j}}{j} \binom{p-1}{j} =\frac{a}{b}$$
>   Which $a,b\in \mathbb Z$ and $\gcd(a,b)=1$.
>   Prove that: $p^2\mid a$.

My idea is the following:

For every $n\in \mathbb N$ and every real $x$ which $|x|<1$, we have :

$$\sum_{j=0}^{n}x^j=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$$
By integration from both side:

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}\frac{x^j}{j}&=\int_0^x\frac{1-t^{n+1}}{1-t}dt\\
&=-\ln(1-x)-\int_{0}^{x}\frac{t^{n+1}}{1-t}dt\\
&=-\ln(1-x)-\int_{1-x}^{1}\frac{(1-z)^{n+1}}{z}dz\\
&=-\ln(1-x)-\int_{1-x}^{1}\frac{1}{z}(\sum_{j=0}^{n+1}(-1)^{n+1-j}\binom{n+1}{j}z^j)dz\\
&=-\ln(1-x)+\ln(1-x)-\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}(-1)^{n+1-j}\binom{n+1}{j}(\int_{1-x}^{1}z^{j-1}dz)\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1-j}}{j}\binom{n+1}{j}\{(1-x)^{j}-1\}\\
&=(-1)^{n+1}\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}\frac{(-1)^{j}}{j}\binom{n+1}{j}\{(1-x)^{j}-1\}
\end{align}
$$

Since the equality is valid for $|x| < 1$, and both side are polynomial, so the equality is true for every $z\in \mathbb C$. So if we put $x=1$ and $n=p-2$ then:

$$\sum_{j=1}^{p-1}\frac{(-1)^j}{j} \binom{p-1}{j}=-\sum_{j=1}^{p-1}\frac{1}{j}$$

So, when:

$$\sum_{j=1}^{p-1}\frac{(-1)^j}{j} \binom{p-1}{j}=\frac{a}{b}$$

We have:
$$\sum_{j=1}^{p-1}\frac{1}{j}=-\frac{a}{b}$$

But by the [Wolstenholme's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1256032/1-frac12-frac13-frac1p-1-fracab/1256045#1256045) we know , when:

$$\sum_{j=1}^{p-1}\frac{1}{j}=-\frac{a}{b}$$

Then, $p^2\mid a$.

Is there another solution to this question without using Wolstenholme's theorem ?