# Sum of Inverses of the elements in $\mathbb Z_p^*$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

If $p $ is an odd prime and if $1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots +\frac{1}{p-1}=\frac{a}{b}$
where $a,b $ are integers prove that $p|a$. If $p>3\implies p^2|a$

**My Try:**

Can the problem be interpreted as a problem in $\mathbb Z_p^*$ where $p$ is an odd prime. Thus we have the sum of inverses of all the elements in $\mathbb Z_p^*$. Also $\mathbb Z_p^*$ is cyclic.

Can all these facts be used in some manner to conclude the answer? Or it is not the way?

Comment: $p|a$ in $\Bbb Z_p$ means $a=0$ which is not even in $\mathbb Z_p^*$.

Comment: But you're on the right track, need to show the sum of all elements in $\mathbb Z_p^*$ equals $\overline0$ in $\mathbb Z_p$

Comment: See here: [ Wolstenholme's theorem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1256032/1-frac12-frac13-frac1p-1-fracab)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**
$$
1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{p-1}=1+2+\cdots+(p-1)  \mod p.
$$