# For a prime $p>3$, if $1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{p-1}=\frac{a}{b}$, then $p^2 \mid a$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-number-theory, finite-fields

Let $p$ be an odd prime and consider the sum $$1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{p-1}=\frac{a}{b},$$ where $a,b$ are integers. Then I showed that $p \mid a$.

> But now I have to show that if $p>3$, a prime, and if $$1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{p-1}=\frac{a}{b},$$ where $a,b$ are integers, then $p^2 \mid a$.

For the first part I did the following. Consider the group homomorphism $\Bbb{F}_p^* \to \Bbb{F}_p^*$ given by $x\mapsto x^{-1}$. Since this map is one to one this is a bijection, $\Bbb{F}_p^*$ being a finite set. Thus $$1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{p-1}=1+2+\cdots+(p-1)=\frac{p(p-1)}{2}$$, thus $pb(p-1)=2a\implies p \mid a$, since $p$ is an odd prime.
But this process no longer works for the next part. What can I do? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hint: this doesn't require groups at all. Add $\frac1i$ and $\frac1{p-i}$ together first.

Comment: Your final set of equalities are not equalities, they are congruences modulo $p$.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1318510/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1284553/42969 – all found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%241%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%7D%2B%5Ccdots%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bp-1%7D%3D%5Cfrac%7Ba%7D%7Bb%7D%24%2C%20AND%20content%3A%24p%5E2%20%5Cmid%20a%24)